# How can I find the user ID using ansible and use that in a jinja2 template?

Tags: variables, ansible, jinja2

I have to create a number of users using ansible. I pass the users as a list inside my ansible play in the vars section:

```
  vars:
    users: ['user1', 'user2']
```

I then have to create a script that uses this users' ID as an argument. The command inside the script is something like this:

`blobfuse $1 --tmp-path=/mnt/resource/{{ item }}/ -o attr_timeout=240 -o entry_timeout=240 -o negative_timeout=120 -o uid=$USER_ID -o allow_other --container-name={{ item }} --file-cache-timeout-in-seconds=120 --config-file=/root/connection-{{ item }}.cfg`

Everything works fine, with the exception of **uid=**
I have tried with the lookup's pipe plugin but this doesn't get me the correct UID:

`{{ lookup('pipe', 'grep -w {{ item }} /etc/passwd | cut -d : -f3') }}`

My end goal is to get the UID of each of the created users, and pass that to the blobfuse command above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about using `id` command and subshell? You can then do something like

`blobfuse $1 --tmp-path=/mnt/resource/{{ item }}/ -o attr_timeout=240 -o entry_timeout=240 -o negative_timeout=120 -o uid="$(id {{ item }})" -o allow_other --container-name={{ item }} --file-cache-timeout-in-seconds=120 --config-file=/root/connection-{{ item }}.cfg`

If you are using command module - you'll have to replace it with shell.

**Edit:** If you are using templates and want to use lookup plugin, which seems cleaner, you can do something like this (this was tested on local linux machine):

**template.yaml**

```
{% for item in users %}
{{ item }} {{ lookup('pipe', "id -u " + item) }}
{% endfor %}
```

**ansible command**

`ansible -m template -i localhost, all -c local  -a "src=template.yaml dest=result.txt" -e "{ users: [nobody,root]}"`

**result.txt**

```
nobody 65534
root 0
```

In your case the error was using the {{ item }} in lookup, you should use just variable names and concatenation inside {{}} block

Comment: i'm using jinja2. the blobfuse command above is in a jinja template, and that's where i need to get the user id to

YET, this works as it will evaluate the $(id -u {{item}}) in the template with $(id -u user) which is the user id.

A good work-around thank you

Comment: @Florin, updated answer for template case, it looks cleaner now

Comment: use ansible modules where you can , don't script it

Answer (score 17):

Q: ***"Get the UID of each created user."***

A: The module [*getent*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/getent_module.html#getent-a-wrapper-to-the-unix-getent-utility) serves exactly this purpose. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    my_users: [root, admin]

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ item }} uid: {{ getent_passwd[item].1 }}
          {{ item }} gid: {{ getent_passwd[item].2 }}
          {{ item }} home: {{ getent_passwd[item].4 }}
          {{ item }} shell: {{ getent_passwd[item].5 }}
      loop: "{{ my_users }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [debug] ************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=root) =>
  msg: |-
    root uid: 0
    root gid: 0
    root home: /root
    root shell: /bin/bash
ok: [localhost] => (item=admin) => 
  msg: |-
    admin uid: 1002
    admin gid: 1002
    admin home: /home/admin
    admin shell: /bin/bash
```

The dictionary *`getent_passwd`*, automatically created by the module *`getent`*, can be also used in a template. For example, the [*Jinja*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#) template below

```yaml
shell> cat my_users.txt.j2
{% for user in my_users %}
{{ user }} {{ getent_passwd[user].1 }}
{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: my_users.txt.j2
        dest: my_users.txt
```

gives

```bash
shell> cat my_users.txt 
root 0
admin 1002
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same question.

Unfortunately, the lookup plugin is only useful on the *control node*.
In other words, the subjected users (with the same **uid**) need to be on both the *control node* and all the *managed nodes*. Or the task will fail with return code 1.

For me, using the **getent** module is a decent solution.
Alternatively, everything is actually there in the returned value of the **user** module. I only need to register its returned value to access them.

The playbook below demonstrates how I compute **uid** from the returned value of the user module both in an arbitrary subsequent task (debug) and in the jinja template.

```yaml
- name: Demonstrate How to Compute UID after User Creations
  hosts: all
  become: true
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    my_users:
      - u1
      - u2
      - u3
  tasks:
    - name: Create users in loop
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_users }}"
      register: created_users

    - name: Display created users
      debug:
        msg: "User: uid:{{ item.uid }} name:{{ item.name }} group:{{ item.group }} home:{{ item.home }} shell:{{ item.shell }}"
      loop: "{{ created_users.results }}"
      # Use loop_control-label to suppress item verbosity
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"

    - name: Work with template
      template:
        src: myusers.j2
        dest: /tmp/myusers.txt
```

And here is myusers.j2 template.

```
{{ ansible_managed | comment }}
{% for item in created_users.results %}
User: uid:{{ item.uid }} name:{{ item.name }} group:{{ item.group }} home:{{ item.home }} shell:{{ item.shell }}
{% endfor %}
```

The output is as follows:

```
$ ansible-playbook compute-uid.yml

PLAY [Demonstrate How to Compute UID after User Creations] **********************************************************************************************

TASK [Create users in loop] *****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ansible1] => (item=u1)
changed: [ansible1] => (item=u2)
changed: [ansible1] => (item=u3)

TASK [Display created users] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [ansible1] => (item=u1) => {
    "msg": "User: uid:1001 name:u1 group:1001 home:/home/u1 shell:/bin/bash"
}
ok: [ansible1] => (item=u2) => {
    "msg": "User: uid:1002 name:u2 group:1002 home:/home/u2 shell:/bin/bash"
}
ok: [ansible1] => (item=u3) => {
    "msg": "User: uid:1003 name:u3 group:1003 home:/home/u3 shell:/bin/bash"
}

TASK [Work with template] *******************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [ansible1]

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ansible1                   : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

$ ansible all -a "cat /tmp/myusers.txt"
ansible1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
#
# Ansible managed
#
User: uid:1001 name:u1 group:1001 home:/home/u1 shell:/bin/bash
User: uid:1002 name:u2 group:1002 home:/home/u2 shell:/bin/bash
User: uid:1003 name:u3 group:1003 home:/home/u3 shell:/bin/bash
```